# Events and Command Binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events, textbox, commandbinding

I have a textbox in WPF and bind a command to its LostFocus event and do some validation in that command.

Now on the same window i have a Save button whose Key binding is Ctrl + S.

If a make some changes in textbox and then push Ctrl + S, it executes the save command without raising the Lost focus event on my textbox.

I know this is by design.

But i want to execute that piece of code before save command, i can't hardcode that code in save process, i want to execute it only when the focus is in textbox.

Comment: Are you able to run the validation code otherwise? If yes, then make it set a flag like isValidated = true. And in your save command run the save code only if the flag is set to true.

Comment: @ryadavilli That'll definitely work, but it seems more like a hack. Is there any genuine solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to factor the validation code out into a separate method that can be called by both the LostFocus and the Save command. Calling the LostFocus from the Save is a bad way of implementing this logic.

The new method can return a boolean to indicate whether the validation succeeded or not. There are better ways of doing validation that don't rely on binding a LostFocus command, check my blog post [*Taking data binding, validation and MVVM to the next level - part 1*](http://techfilth.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/taking-databinding-validation-and-mvvm.html) for more ideas.

Comment: Great article, very enlighting. But there is a catch my textbox contains Phone no and thus some basic formatting. I do this formatting when user validates the textbox upon lost focus. As per your article i need to update source property everytime user make some change in it. If i do so, on every change my constructor gets fired and format the data in the textbox.